# How do I limit project-wide search/replace to my own files only?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have included the boost libraries in my project, and when I do a search/replace (*ctrl+f*) and choose *Current Project* Visual Studio 2013 looks through and replaces matches in my own files (intended) and every boost header and source file (*not* intended).

In Visual Studio 2012 I never had this problem, it only started when I installed Visual Studio 2013 RC.

Is this a bug or a feature? Any ideas on how to fix it?

My version of Visual Studio 2013 is 12.0.20827.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need to double check your "Look in" settings to make sure you are not selecting "including external items"?

[image]